# Before Insert Trigger on Opportunity

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex

Maybe someone can help clarify this for me.

I'm trying to write a before insert trigger on opportunity to set closedate if it's left blank.  Is this possible?

There's not much code to show. All i did was create a simple before insert trigger with a debug statement to make sure my trigger was executing before the validation rule.  It appears that the validation rule is first (and i apparently can't alter it).  The trigger never fires.

Should this be working or is it impossible?

Comment: please post your trigger code.

Answer (score 0):

Validation Rule should run after before trigger. Please refer to the [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) (Step 3 & 4).

If you could paste your code here, I could look deeper into it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deactivate the validation rule.
Have a look at the Execution order:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm

So basically if you want to use a trigger to check you empty dates:

- To auto populate the value -> before insert trigger
- To throw an error when it is empty -> after insert trigger